# Создание структуры из массива байт

Tags: c#, c, .net

В исходном коде, который зашит в устройство есть такая структура:

```
__packed struct {
uint32_t    Sec : 6 ;
uint32_t    Min : 6 ;
uint32_t    Hour : 5 ;
uint32_t    Date : 5 ;
uint32_t    Month : 4 ;
uint8_t     Year : 7 ;
uint8_t     TimeInvalid : 1 ;
} Time ;
```

Данная структура помещается в массив из 5 байт.
Как обработать эту структуру на C#? Проблема в том, что поля структуры не разделены по отдельным байтам.
Есть ли возможность создать структуры с полями, у которых указан размер в битах?
И как создать структуру из массива байтов?

Answer (score 3):

C# нативно не поддерживает битовые поля. Придется делать структуру(или массив) из пяти байт. И работать с ними в ручную. Либо использовать разные [хаки](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095576/Bit-Field-in-Csharp-using-struct)

Вот как можно описать структуру:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=0)]
struct ExampleStruct
{
   public byte b1;
   public byte b2;
   public byte b3;
   public byte b4;
   public byte b5;   
}
```