# Аналог структуры C++ с битовыми полями в C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

Объясните, выделяется размер для следующей структуры

```
struct BURInSyncStruct
{
    uint16_t Sync1 : 12;
    uint16_t Sync2 : 12;
    uint16_t Sync3 : 12;
    uint16_t Sync4 : 12;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

и как записать такую структуру на C#? Я пытался записать следующим образом

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct BURInSyncStruct
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort Sync1;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public ushort Sync2;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public ushort Sync3;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public ushort Sync4;
}
```

но, мне кажется, это не верно.

Comment: Это упакованная структура с битовыми полями. Каждое поле занимает 12 бит. Всего размер структуры 6 байт. Вопрос скорее всего [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764140/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82/764141#764141)

Answer (score 5):

Естественно, это неверно. В С++ 4 битовых поля по 12 бит, расположенных вплотную без пропусков ( `__attribute__((packed))`). В вашем объявлении для С# 4 обыкновенных поля ushort, накладывающихся друг на друга. Как сделать правильно? В C# нет битовых полей, но есть класс BitConverter и битовые операции, которые позволяют реализовать их.

Битовые маски для установки полей Sync1 и Sync2 выглядят так:

```
Байт №: |       5|       4|       3|       2|       1|       0| 
                                             00001111 11111111   = 0x0FFF
                                                   Sync1

Байт №: |       5|       4|       3|       2|       1|       0|
                                    11111111 11110000 00000000   = 0xFFF000
                                          Sync2
```

Это приводит нас к такому коду:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct BURInSyncStruct
{
    public static BURInSyncStruct Create()
    {
        BURInSyncStruct s = new BURInSyncStruct();
        s.data = new byte[6];
        return s;
    }

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public byte[] data;                       

    public ushort Sync1
    {
        get
        {                    
            byte[] bytes64 = new byte[8];
            Array.Copy(data, bytes64, data.Length);
            ulong x = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes64, 0);

            ulong y = x & 0x0FFF;                    
            return (ushort)y;
        }

        set
        {
            byte[] bytes64 = new byte[8];
            Array.Copy(data, bytes64, data.Length);
            ulong x = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes64, 0);
            x = x & ~((ulong)0x0FFF);

            ulong y = (ulong)value & 0x0FFF;
            ulong res = x | y;
            bytes64 = BitConverter.GetBytes(res);
            Array.Copy(bytes64, data, data.Length);
        }
    }

    public ushort Sync2
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] bytes64 = new byte[8];
            Array.Copy(data, bytes64, data.Length);
            ulong x = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes64, 0);
            ulong y = x & 0xFFF000;
            y = y >> 12;                       
            return (ushort)y;
        }

        set
        {
            byte[] bytes64 = new byte[8];
            Array.Copy(data, bytes64, data.Length);
            ulong x = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes64, 0);
            x = x & ~((ulong)0xFFF000);

            ulong y = (ulong)(value << 12) & 0xFFF000;                    
            ulong res = x | y;
            bytes64 = BitConverter.GetBytes(res);
            Array.Copy(bytes64, data, data.Length);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: А для чего копирование в `get`? Можно ведь напрямую из данных взять. Что-то типа `public ushort Sync1 { get => (ushort)(BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 0) & 0x0FFF); set { ... } }`, соответственно для второго `public ushort Sync2 { get => (ushort)((BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 1) & 0xFFF0) >> 4); set { ... } }`. Да и в `set` наверное можно прямо по `data` работать.

Comment: @i-one Копирование мне нужно было чтобы работать со всей структурой как с одним значением ulong. Это первое что пришло в голову, да, конечно можно сделать это проще.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46279898/2523686) и [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e0017b19-a376-4303-876d-d71cb136454f) упоминается, что вместо _struct_ можно использовать _class_ (хотя случаи там не идентичные). Можно ли в данном случае использовать _class_?

Comment: @i-one На первый взгляд можно. В этом случае можно сделать нормальный конструктор. Маршаллер должен работать с классами, имеющими атрибут StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential) так же, как и со структурами, но я не пробовал на практике.