# Как на C# задавать расположение данных в памяти с точностью до бит с помощью структур

Tags: c#, c, struct, union

Есть структура на С, которая используется для распределения данных пакета по его полям. В С# я новичок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать ее на C#? Все, что пока нашел, - возможность использовать атрибуты вроде `[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Explicit)]` и `[FieldOffset(n)]`. (
[FieldOffsetAttribute Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute?view=netframework-4.8))
Проблема в том, что поле address должно занимать 6 бит, поле type - вообще два; а, насколько я понял,  FieldOffset задает смещение поля кратно байту, а не биту.

Собственно структура на С:

```
struct SExpandedPackage
{
    unsigned char address : 6;
    unsigned char type    : 2;
    unsigned char adata   : 4;
    unsigned char command : 4;
    unsigned char data       ;
    unsigned char crc        ;
};

union uPackageContainer
{
    unsigned long      bits;
    unsigned char      bytes[sizeof(unsigned long)];
    struct SExpandedPackage   expanded;
};
```

Comment: Пример работы с битами в структурах можно посмотреть например здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004175/

Comment: to MSDN.'Reinstate Monica' Knight:
Спасибо! Изучаю и сразу пробую, но пока безрезультатно.

Comment: to  PashaPash: спасибо! Разобрался :)

Answer (score 5):

Для себя вопрос решил. Поля, составляющие 1 байт - в нем и хранятся (Это address и type, command и adata). Доступ к ним осуществляю с помощью битовых масок, которые применяются в соответствующих геттерах и сеттерах. Еще раз - спасибо MSDN.'Reinstate Monica' Knight за толчок в нужном направлении, и PashaPash за помощь в оформлении!

Код на С#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct PackageContainer
    {
        private const byte _pkg_type = 0xC0;
        private const byte _pkg_address = 0x3F;
        private const byte _pkg_cmd = 0xF0;
        private const byte _pkg_adata = 0x0F;

        [FieldOffset(0)] private byte pkg_type;
        [FieldOffset(0)] private byte pkg_address;
        [FieldOffset(1)] private byte pkg_cmd;
        [FieldOffset(1)] private byte pkg_adata;

        public byte Pkg_Type
        {   // 2-битное значение
            get { return (byte)((pkg_type & _pkg_type) >> 6); }
            set { pkg_type = (byte)((pkg_type & ~_pkg_type) | (value << 6) & _pkg_type); }
        }
        public byte Pkg_Address
        {   // 6-битное значение
            get { return (byte)(pkg_address & _pkg_address); }
            set { pkg_address = (byte)((pkg_address & ~_pkg_address) | (_pkg_address & value)); }
        }
    }
```

*Еще хорошо помогла [статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/114953/).